# Difference between symlink and alias

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, symlink, bash

I was trying to set up opening sublime text editor from terminal on Mac OS.

When I was searching for that I found out one way to do that: create soft link (symlink) and change the path in .profile by ***ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime*** but since PATH did not change in .profile I just added ***alias sublime=' open /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'***

Could you please tell me what is the difference between these ways?Which way is better?How to change PATH from terminal not opening .profile?

Comment: Symlink creates a symbolic link of the source file in the target. Whenever a symbolic file is executed, the real file is executed. Alias is a name you want to call the real file. Alias persists on the session and is gone when a sub-shell is invoked. To make alias persistent, it can be added in the profile. Symbolic link persists in the file system and does not require to be added to the profile. If you are using bash, it uses `.bash_profile`, not `.profile`.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have .bash_profile, I have only .profile.
Could you also please tell me what is more professional and favorable to do: symlink or alias?

Comment: Alias is more preferred. Avoid symlink at all cost. It may affect other users or system processes that looks at the path and may be using a similarly named file.